# firebase authentication - does firebase differentiate facebook and google login accounts

Tags: android, facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to use firebase as my apps authentication method.  But I'd like my users to log in using Google or Facebook. I am a little confused what happens here.

Lets say a user successfully authenticates with Facebook only. Then I get a callback from Facebook with some token of success. Now I send that token to firebase for further authentication.
Firebase can return success or failure. This part I understand.

But what I am confused about is if the same user uses the Google account to login, will that not be considered a different login?  Will firebase know that the Facebook user is the same google user or will it create two different accounts? I don't want the user to have two different accounts because they chose a different login provider. I want firebase to be able to know its the same user. That is why I wanted to user firebase authentication as its a central place. Can someone advise me?

UPDATE:

Thanks. So if I understand correctly at least one account must already be currently logged into firebase inorder to link another one ? So that being the case ...imagine i am currently logged in with a google account. How would i ask the user to link there facebook account? I wish i could link the second account seamlessly but seems you cant. Therefore how doni prompt the user or under what condition can i link the second account effortlessly? I'm having trouble visualizing how this would work without me directly asking the user.

Answer (score 3):

As long as the user uses the same email address for both providers, you can tell Firebase to link the two accounts together. See the [section on linking providers in the Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking).

Comment: Account linking can be quite seamless, but will always require some action from the user. It would be pretty bad actually if an app would magically connect the user's Facebook + Google + Twiter accounts without asking them to sign in to those profiles. If you're having trouble making it work, share the [minimum code that reproduces where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Firebase supports multiple Auth Providers to an Account. All you have to do is to use linkWithCredential(credential) method. Here is a code snipset from firebase website.

```
mAuth.getCurrentUser().linkWithCredential(credential)
    .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "linkWithCredential:success");
                FirebaseUser user = task.getResult().getUser();
                updateUI(user);
            } else {
                Log.w(TAG, "linkWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                Toast.makeText(AnonymousAuthActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                updateUI(null);
            }

            // ...
        }
    });
```

Take note that the call to linkWithCredential will fail if the credentials are already linked to another user account. In this situation, you must handle merging the accounts and associated data as appropriate for your app.